# UITableView called many times when the cell is out of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem when i use the function `tableView`. I show you my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cardCell", for: indexPath) as! OpsCardCell
    cell.workTest(drawCard: .selectOpponent)
    return cell
}
```

In the exemple I have 4 cell and when I scroll in the simulator the cell who are out of the screen and come back, the cell is again called. And since I draw the card dynamically, the card was drawn several times and the shadow I adds too many times. I show you the screen before and after:

after few scroll down and scroll up:

this is because the function tableView called many times the cell `[0]` and `[3]`
This is my code to draw the card:

```
func drawBasiqCard(){
        let cardView = UIView()
        self.addSubview(cardView)
        cardView.frame = CGRect(marginCardWidth,
                                marginCardHeight,
                                self.bounds.size.width - (marginCardWidth*2),
                                self.bounds.size.height - (marginCardHeight*2))
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        let rounding = CGFloat.init(10)
        let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
        shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: cardView.bounds, cornerRadius: rounding).cgPath
        shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xaaccbb).cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 0)
        cardView.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
    }
```

So my question is, what is wrong with my code? And there is another way to solve my problem ?

thanks to your reply !

[image]

[image]

Comment: that is how UITableView works. It reuse the cell to save resource. You should check yourself that if it has already been drawed, don't draw again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is cell recycling. When you scroll, the same cell gets re-used to display data at a different indexPath.

You should create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell. Give it an optional property `shadowLayer`. In your `cellForRow(at:)` method, dequeue a cell and cast it to the correct custom class. Then check to see if its `shadowLayer` property is nil. If it is nil, add a shadow layer. If it's not nil, create a shadow layer and install it in the cell (`cell.shadowLayer = shadowLayer`).

Comment: Thanks, I just add a if statement to see if a shadow layer exist. I post in my own post a reply to show the code for help other people.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to add sublayer at once in your awakefromnib method. Tableviewcell reuse the same cell using cell identifier that why multiple shadows added to your cell.

Comment: Thanks to your reply, yes I test now if a shadowLayer exist and if no, I add it.

Comment: Yes it is also an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

In you code you have taken new card each time that card drawing method called, so this will work fine for the first time, but after that this will create problem because you haven't removed that view or you have not checked is that card is already added in cell or not.

So you can either remove below line from you code and take one parent view to design your card inside your storyboard or xib, if you are going to design your cell using xib or storyboard.

```
let cardView = UIView()
```

Or if you are going to design your cell programatically then first check if that `cardview` is added in cell or not, and then `cardview` is not added then add new one else skip that code.

Comment: Yes so, I make the same that I do to the shadowLayer, I write private `let cardView = UIView()` and I test with a if statement  `cardView.subviews.count == 0` but this not work, another solution ?

Answer (score 1):

So I add to the top of my class :

```
private var ShadowLayerCard: CAShapeLayer?
```

and I compare if the `ShadowLayerCard` is not `nil` :

```
if(self.ShadowLayerCard == nil){
     let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
     self.ShadowLayerCard = shadowLayer

     // here I have my code to add the shadowLayer and other parameters of the shadow...       
}
```

this solve my problem, thanks to [duncan-c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205185/duncan-c)